# Travel changes with an Iranian visa

Tags: visas, iran, visa-extensions

I received my Iranian visa two days ago. My plan was to go there for a week, but unexpectedly I have an extra week available (due to an event in Turkey being cancelled just recently). Therefore I would like to extend my stay in Iran - to be precise enter the country before the date I put in my application. The itinerary would change a bit too.

Is this a problem? According to the date printed on it, my visa is valid for the entire period. Do I have to notify the embassy or the Police Department of Foreign Affairs or the party, I got my invitation from, about these changes?

What is the best way to handle the situation? I don't want to run into any problems, but I also don't want to miss the chance of spending some extra days there.

Comment: So you don't have the visa yet, you just want to modify your application ?

Comment: No, I already received my visa. It's valid for the entire trip. The question is, if I need to inform someone about the fact, that I'll travel at different dates than I originally mentioned in the application. I'll update my question to clarify.

Comment: If the visa also covers the extra week you intend to spend, there shouldn't be a problem

Comment: I agree with @Fiksdal. I don't think there would be any problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, it's the validity of your actual visa that matters. Once you have your visa, much of what you wrote in your application doesn't matter so much anymore. Travellers change their plans all the time. The Iranian government has given you an official document permitting you to enter and exit Iran within a certain timespan. As long you stick to that, there will be no problem whatsoever. I guess you could email the Iranian foreign mission which issued your visa, informing them of the changes in your itinerary, but I really don't think it's necessary at all. If they had wanted to restrict you to just the dates you mentioned in the application, they could have issued a shorter visa.